# Retrieve display property using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<style type="text/css"> a { display: none; } </style> 

<p id="p"> a paragraph </p> 
<a href="google.com"; id="a">google</a>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var a = (document.getElementById('a')).style; 
   alert(a.display); 
   var p = (document.getElementById('p')).style; 
   alert(p.display); 
   p.display = 'none'; 
   alert(p.display);
</script>
```

How could I retrieve the display property of anchor tag correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
var value = $(element).css('display')
```

Comment: <style type="text/css">   a {    display: none;      }  </style>
        <p id="p"> a paragraph </p>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" id="a">google</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = (document.getElementById('a')).style;
        alert(a.display);
        var p = (document.getElementById('p')).style;
        alert(p.display);
        p.display = 'none';
        alert(p.display);
    </script>
How could I retrieve the display property of anchor tag correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: @Selvaraj: Exactly as explained in this answer. Note that your HTML is invalid, there is not supposed to be a colon after `href="google.com"`.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery

```
$('.element').css('display');
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/